# multiple input parameters from command line in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to pass multiple parameters when running a compiled C code

code would be like this

```
void main(char argc,char *argv[]){

    printf("%s",argv[1])    //filename
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r")

    printf("%s",argv[2])    //function to be called
    char* func_name = argv[2];

    printf("%s",argv[3])    //how many times the function is called
    int repeat = argv[3];

    for(int i=0;i<repeat;i++){
        func_name(file) //calls some function and passes the file to it 
    }
```

}

i would compile like this

```
gcc cprog.c -o cprog
```

run like -

```
./cprog textfile.txt function1 4
```

how do i do this ? any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You do it like that (that is, if your question is about command line parameters, if your question is about calling a function from its name, that's another question).

Comment: Remember that the entries in the `argv` array are *strings* and you can't simply can't cast a string into a number, you have to use e.g. `strtol` to convert the string. Other than that your code is fine with regards to the command line arguments.

Comment: You won't be able to pass the name of the function to be called via `argv[2]`.

Comment: I am afraid it won't be easy, as C does not store function names in the binary. You'll have to make some kind of calling table where you link strings to function pointers.

Comment: @bart ...ok, then I could have some thing like a number from command line and then a if-else block to call particular functions perhaps ?

Comment: How come `func_name(file)` will run your function `repeat` times ?
Are you under impression that your code will get re-compile to an executable binary ?

Comment: @Sid5427 yes that could be a way. Do remember what people have said about `strtol` though.

Comment: @POW ... that's question ain't it ? that will it work or not ? I just want to pass a number for 'repeat'

Comment: @KerrekSB .. opps .. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off:

1. You are missing some semicolons, so your code won't even compile.
2. `argv[]` are *strings*, so you'll have to convert them to integers if you want to use them as such.
3. C does not store function names in the binary, so you have to create some kind of calling table.

Below find a working example. I creates a `struct` that maps a name to a function, implement that function and go look for it. It's quite buggy (no input validation is done), but gives you a proof of concept on how to possibly implement this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct fcn_entry {
  char *name;
  void (*fcn)(char *);
};

void fcn1(char *fn) {
   printf("fcn1: %s\n", fn);
}

void fcn2(char *fn) {
   printf("fcn2: %s\n", fn);
}

void main(char argc,char *argv[]){
    // name-to-function table
    struct fcn_entry entries[] = {
        { "fcn1", fcn1 },
        { "fcn2", fcn2 },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };
    void (*fcn_to_call)(char *);
    int i = 0;

    printf("%s",argv[1]);    //filename

    printf("%s",argv[2]);    //function to be called    
    char* func_name = argv[2];
    i = 0;
    while(entries[i].name != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(entries[i].name, func_name) == 0) {
           fcn_to_call = entries[i].fcn;
           break;
        } else {
           fcn_to_call = NULL;
        }
        i++;
    }


    printf("%s",argv[3]);    //how many times the function is called
    int repeat = atoi(argv[3]);

    for(i=0;i<repeat;i++){
        fcn_to_call(argv[1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to call a function that you have as a string, you have know which name is paired to which function.

If all functions take the same arguments, you can have an array of structures with name and function pointer, and then match the name with the correct entry in the table.

Otherwise, if the arguments are different you have to have a chain of `strcmp` calls to call the correct function.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lots of error here.

```
int repeat = argv[3]; //You must convert char* to int before assignment.
func_name(file)       //func_name is a char* not a function. C does not support reflection so there is no way to call function like this.
```